# global object window is undefined in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, window, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add some scroll feature and it says window is undefined. I thought window was a global object in JS... how must I define it?

```js
created() {
  const top = window.load.pageYOffset || 0;
  if (top <= 60) {
    this.color = "transparent";
    this.flat = true;
  }
},
```

Comment: What if you try it in `mounted`?

Comment: What is the mode (universal or SPA) you're using? If it is universal then I think you'll need to make sure that this line of code runs on client side rather than on the server side, please do something like this:  if (process.client) {
    const top = window.load.pageYOffset || 0;
  if (top <= 60) {
    this.color = "transparent";
    this.flat = true;
  }
}, if still isn't working then try on mounted.

Answer (score 0):

`window` should not be undefined, however `window.load` will be (is that what you meant?)

Use `window.pageYOffset` instead.

Comment: I would think the same. There is no typo yet vue still says window is undefined...